# Vertically moving wings

Tags: aircraft-design, theory

Would there be a benefit to vertically adjustable main wings?

I recently watched this anime series and got curious if the wing moving mechanism could have any plus points, or if it was likely just purely for the rule of cool. Being able to be stored in smaller spaces does not count.

The aircraft is [yukikaze](http://www.gearsonline.net/series/yukikaze/mave/) from [Sentō Yōsei Yukikaze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukikaze_(novel)).

[image]
edit: a second image where the wings are down to show the difference
[image]

Comment: Do you have a drawing that depicts the moving wings? I can't recognise them in the third-angle projection you posted.

Comment: @Bergi if you compare the top right depiction of the aircraft on the top image and the aircraft on the bottom image you will see that the wing can bend up and down

Answer (score 17):

If you ever wonder what different types of wing motions are good for, look at birds. They use all of them.

In this case it reduces lift while keeping drag the same. Birds use this when landing. It also adds dihedral.

For our much larger aircraft, we use spoilers due to scaling issues.

Many, if not most or all, motions involving the entire wing can be used for control in place of things like elevators, ailerons, flaps, spoilers, and rudders. But they have more value at smaller scales where structural scaling causes strength of materials to no longer be an issue and where aerodynamic scaling causes the conventional control surfaces to be too small.

Answer (score 12):

The [XB-70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_XB-70_Valkyrie) had wingtips that folded down in flight so it could use the shock wave to create additional lift.  However this particular approach ([compression lift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_lift)) only applies to supersonic airplanes.

[image]
(picture from Wikipedia)

I can't think of any other planes that allowed any part of the wing to move vertically for aerodynamic reasons.

Comment: the weird thing is that the wings get angled upwards, and seem to stay in that position at all times in the air.

Comment: @NajLitarvan Well, it is fiction after all - I doubt anyone did a CFD study of the 3D models used in the anime series.

Answer (score 1):

No there would not be much benefit to change the incidence angle of the main wings in flight. Dihedral plays mainly a role in passive lateral stability, and there are quite a few fighter planes around that don't have passive stability anyway - for instance the F-16 which has an aerodynamically unstable airframe in pitch, which is made controllable for a human through active stabilisation by the fly-by-wire computers.

As usual in aircraft design manufacturing, construction plays as large a role as aerodynamics do. And to make a wing that can make a flapping motion does not create any manoeuvrability benefit that I can think of, but *does* create large structural challenges. The main wings need to absorb the manoeuvrability loads of up to 9g, and it would be great if the projected wing area is not reduced by pointing the wing tips up.

> Would there be a benefit to vertically adjustable main wings?

Not really, no.

Comment: Does "on takeoff and landing" count? Because the F-8 Crusader's variable-incidence-angle wings won the designers a Collier Trophy...

Comment: we are not talking pitch , the airplane can adjust the plane on the roll axis of rotation

Comment: The F-8s variable incidence wing really only changed the angle of the fuselage, ( the wing pretty much stayed at the same angle to the ground on approach). Lowering the fuselage angle allowed the pilot to see the runway, (the boat), much better.

Comment: @NajLitarvan Sorry, I do not understand what that means. Is it like in @ 
UnrecognizedFallingObject's comment? If so, ti requires a totally different answer and I will update it.

Comment: we not talking the wings rotating around the pitch axis(front to back), but roll axis (rotating from left to right, the same axis an aileron roll maneuver is executed.